# Sum of cells containing a formula in google sheets

Tags: google-sheets, filter, sum, google-sheets-formula, sumifs

I want the sum of values in a column. However I wish to ignore cells which do not contain a formula. I tried

```
 =SUMIF(A1:A10, ISFORMULA(A1:A10))
```

But that did not work

Answer (score 1):

if its a small range you can do:

```
=SUM(FILTER(A1:A10, {ISFORMULA(A1); ISFORMULA(A2); ISFORMULA(A3); 
                     ISFORMULA(A4); ISFORMULA(A5); ISFORMULA(A6); 
                     ISFORMULA(A7); ISFORMULA(A8); ISFORMULA(A9); ISFORMULA(A10)})
```

[image: 0]

Comment: Thank you. There is probably a more general way to do this in google sheets.

Comment: not rly because ISFORMULA is not supported under arrayformula

Answer (score 1):

This way might work for you.
I added a column with the following formula, which unfortunately also doesn't work as an arrayformula.  But if you put this at the top of your column, beside the one you want to sum, and double click the "drag down" blue square on the bottom right corner of the cell, it will fill all the way down, provided you have no blank rows.  Dragging down also works obviously.

```
=IFNA(FORMULATEXT(A1),0)
```

This creates a column of zeroes and text formulas, which you can use as a filter for your SUMIF formula, as follows: (assumes data column is A1:A30, helper column is B1:B30.  SUMIF is in C1)

```
=SUMIF(B1:B30,"=0",A1:A30)
```

[image]

Let me know if this is useful, or not.

Comment: Useful. Thank you. After seeing your solution, I'm wondering if ISNA (instead of IFNA) can be used in conjunction with SumIf or SumIfs

Comment: Not quite sure how you are thinking of using `ISNA`.  The issue is finding a way to identify all of the values we want to sum in a column, or flag the ones we want to ignore.  I haven't found an arrayformula that does that.  But using `IFNA` to force the ones that "fail" the `FORMULATEXT` conversion to a value of zero, helps do that.  I can't see a way to use `ISNA` with `FORMULATEXT` that makes that any easier?